# Gain access on each element of an array which is inside a function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
function sample () { 
var array = [1,2,3,4,4] 
return array
}
```

What is the proper function call here? For example, I wanna access '1' or '2' - sample([0]) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `sample()[0]` should work

Comment: Oh..... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function first:

```js
function sample () { 
  var array = [1,2,3,4,4] 
  return array
} 

console.log( sample()[0] );
console.log( sample()[1] );
```